# How to close server socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have multi-threaded application that is using server socket. This is an Android application. Now, since network interface change (WiFi to Ethernet and vice versa) causes IP to change, I need to close old sockets and open new ones. I am trying to close socket as below; however, the `IOException` kicks in few milliseconds later.

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        read();
        if (stopFlag)
        {
             serverSocket.close(); 
             socket.close();
             break;     
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach ?

Comment: Try closing your socket before your server socket.

Comment: There's nothing clearly wrong with what you're doing. What `IOException` are you seeing (what is its message?), and on which line does it occur?

Comment: @LoganDam That won't change anything. They aren't interdependent.

Comment: Inside read() i am opening input/output stream, and of course, it is inside try-catch, and that is where I get exception. Is is because SocketException wraps IOException ?

Comment: That brings me to ask another question. Is read() a blocking call ? I mean if the stream returns -1 then we know no data read or end of stream has reached. What if nothing is return ? Should it just circle in while loop until I set stopFlag = true ?

Comment: I don't understand where you are closing socket if all goes right? In read method? If you're not closing socket after successful read then another connection accepted give the control to previous socket to garbage collector. Is this normal behavior for your program?

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious No i do not close on successful read because I keep socket alive until the network interface changes. When that happens I just toggle the stopFlag via static method. And when I do that the read method throws IOException.

Comment: Of course it does. It is trying to read on a socket you have just closed. What did you expect? Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ArjunPatel Ok.. I actually still can't understand how you exactly want to communicate with several clients. And how exactly you want to close sockets on success. ) What will happen if you are waiting for connection in accept() and interface went down? accept() will return invalid socket(or perhaps null). You try to write to stream of invalid socket and handle exception setting stopFlag to true and try to close invalid socket(or null). Can this situation cause and exception in socket.close()?